# triming rss before storing it in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rss

I have to trim the rss feed before storing it in isloated storage. my code is

```
var rssData = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
                          select new RSSClass
                          {

                              imageURL = rss.Element("description").Value,
                              imageRef = rss.Element("description").Value,
                              imageLink = rss.Element("link").Value,
                              imageTime = rss.Element("pubDate").Value

                          };
```

i want to trim string before assigning to imageURL. But it did'nt let me do it inside select new RSSClass {} body, for example if i write line 
string temp; before imageURL, it gives error, "invalied expression term". SO where actually i have to trim the rss before storing in isolated storage. Kindly guide me. thanks

Comment: that may be a option , but if i have to do a series of operations before assinging the value. then ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean.

Comment: dear gunr2171. rss.Element("description").Value has two href in it i have to extract it and assign first to imageURL and second to imageRef.

Comment: Can you show an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) needs to go inside your `select`, just after the `Value` you want to assign:

```
imageURL = rss.Element("description").Value.Trim()
```

I am not sure of the behavior if the value passed into the function is `null`, so that would be your only area of concern.